# Remove text after a space across multiple columns in Excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have a list of items' monthly prices and the price columns have both the amount and currencies. I am trying to remove the currencies across multiple columns.

Sample data sets:
[image]

I wrote below macro to remove text after space of cells in A1:E6:

```
Sub RemoveCurrency()
Dim cell As Range
Dim withCurrency As String
Dim PriceOnly As String
For Each cell In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:E6")
    withCurrency = cell.Value
    PriceOnly = Left(withCurrency, InStr(withCurrency, " ") - 1)
    cell.Value = PriceOnly
    Next cell
End Sub
```

After I ran it, it gives me a VB run-time error '5':
Invalid procedure call or argument

Can someone help to debug my VBA code?

Comment: change .`Range("A1:E6")` to .`Range("B3:E6")`

Comment: Thank you! Got to know that the error is caused by cells values with no space

Answer (score 0):

This code is much longer/less efficient than yours, but it won't give you an error when it runs out of cells to edit, at least (it's a module I had already written in the past for nearly the exact same purpose). Alternatively, yours should work (but still error at the end) if you update the range to start at the cell where your currency amount starts. You can read more about VBA ranges in the [MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/range-object-excel).

It requires that you add a VBA reference to "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5" if you don't already have it checked. You can do that in Tools -> References.

```
Public Sub TruncateIDs()

    Dim strPattern As String: strPattern = "[A-Z]{1,3}"
    Dim strReplace As String: strReplace = ""
    Dim regEx As New RegExp
    Dim strInput As String
    Dim MyRange As Range

    Set MyRange = ActiveSheet.Range("B3:E6")
    ActiveSheet.Range("B3").Select

    Do While strPattern <> ""
        strInput = ActiveCell.Value

        With regEx
            .Global = True
            .MultiLine = True
            .IgnoreCase = False
            .Pattern = strPattern
        End With

        If regEx.Test(strInput) Then
            ActiveCell = regEx.Replace(strInput, strReplace)
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        ElseIf ActiveCell = "" Then
            ActiveCell.Offset(-4, 1).Select
            If ActiveCell <> "" Then
                strInput = ActiveCell.Value
                ActiveCell = regEx.Replace(strInput, strReplace)
                ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            Else
                Exit Do
            End If
        Else
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Am I right, reading *"to remove text **after space**"* as "including this space"? If so:

```
Dim sStr$
        ' ...
    For Each cell In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:E6")
        ' ...
        sStr = cell.Value
        If LenB(sStr) Then cell.Value = Split(sStr, " ")(0)
            'or
        cell.Value = Split(sStr & " ", " ")(0)
        ' ...
    Next
' I'm not sure which is faster... but LenB seems to me more realiable
```